# using scrooge in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, thrift, scrooge

when using Finagle you can place the thrift file in the directory `src/main/thrift/`, and when compiling it can generate thrift file automatically in the directory `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/`.
How can the Play framework do the same thing automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to configure the [SBT plugin](https://twitter.github.io/scrooge/SBTPlugin.html) or the [Maven plugin](https://twitter.github.io/scrooge/MVNPlugin.html). Though note that this will still produce Finagle-oriented implementations - Scrooge only really supports those. (I have a pull request outstanding to add support for other kind of server implementations).

Comment: I have configured in my build.sbt and project/plugins.sbt. But , in which directory I put the thrift files can the compiler finds and generate  automatically ?

Comment: I don't know SBT, but whichever one you configured or whichever the plugin defaults to - probably src/main/thrift.